# Problems with wifi connection after playing with aircrack

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

Problem: From time to time my wifi connection download/upload speed goes to nearly 0 for 2-3 minutes (pages doesn't open) and goes back to the full speed after this time. This happens for about half an hour and then everything works good for another half an hour and then it's not working again... It doesn't happen on other computers connected to the same network and happens on 3 different networks.

Possible reasons: A few weeks ago I installed and played a little with aircrack. Maybe, I change some mode/setting in my wlan device by accident?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If your still can connect to Internet, i dont think its aircrack issue. Try check [this post.](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/solved-wireless-network-detected-but.html)

Comment: penreturn, I can connect to Internet, but connection has problems mentioned above. Thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996768 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1884589 solved my problem.

Summing up, there's a bug in intel's IEEE 802.11n driver. Links above help you turning 'n' off.

Comment: @penreturn: done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996768](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996768) and [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1884589](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1884589) solved my problem. Summing up, there's a bug in intel's IEEE 802.11n driver. Links above help you turning 'n' off.